# How to move Menu on Navbar

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I created a menu through the toolbox in C#. The menu is positioned in my navbar however it is to the far right. I usually move it by dragging it through the design screen however that is not an option for me this time. is there a way to move my menu from the far edge of the screen and over to the left some. Here is my code :

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary navbar-fixed-top" >
            
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/Default.aspx">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img class="auto-style1" src="MicrosoftTeams-image%20(5).png" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </a>
     
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarColor01" aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

      </div>
           

     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
<ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
  <li class="nav-item">

        <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/"><asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal" Vertical-align="left" text-align="left" Font-Size="Large" BackColor="White" DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Underline="False" ForeColor="White" Height="16px" RenderingMode="Table" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" BorderColor="White">
                        <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#003057" ForeColor="White" />
                        <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
                        <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#003057" HorizontalPadding="10px" VerticalPadding="5px" />
                        <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#003057" HorizontalPadding="10px" VerticalPadding="5px" />
                        <Items>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="&nbsp; |" Value="|"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="&nbsp; My Profile &nbsp; " Value="My Profile" NavigateUrl="~/My Profile.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="&nbsp;|" Value="|"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="&nbsp;&nbsp; Admin  &nbsp;"  Value="Admin" PopOutImageUrl="~/CaretDown.png">
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/AccessList.aspx" Text="Access List" Value="Access List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Aspnet Application.aspx" Text="Application List" Value="Application List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Computer" Value="Computer" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Computer.aspx" PopOutImageUrl="~/Caret6.png">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ComputerList.aspx" Text="Computer List" Value="Computer List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ComputerTypes.aspx" Text="Computer Type" Value="Computer Types"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ComputerStatusList.aspx" Text="Computer Status List" Value="Computer Status List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ContractsList.aspx" Text="Contract List" Value="Contracts List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/CostTypeList.aspx" Text="Cost Type List" Value="Cost Type List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/DataCenterList.aspx" Text="Data Center List" Value="Data Centers List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/EmpComputer.aspx" Text="Employee Computer List" Value="Employee Computer List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/EmployeeSoftware.aspx" Text="Employee Software List" Value="Employee Software"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Employees" Value="Employees" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Employee.aspx" PopOutImageUrl="~/Caret6.png">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/EmployeeCategoryList.aspx" Text="Employee Category List" Value="Employee Category List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/EmpLicenseList.aspx" Text="Employee License List" Value="Employee License List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/EmployeeList.aspx" Text="Employee List" Value="Employee List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/EmployeeRoleList.aspx" Text="Employee Role List" Value="Employee Role List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/EnvironmentList.aspx" Text="Environment List" Value="Environment List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/HardwareList.aspx" Text="Hardware List" Value="Hardware List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/JobseriesList.aspx" Text="Job Series List" Value="Job Series List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Licenses" Value="&amp;nbsp Licenses" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Licenses.aspx" PopOutImageUrl="~/Caret6.png">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/LicenseList.aspx" Text="License List" Value="License List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/LicenseTypesList.aspx" Text="License Types" Value="License Types"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/LicenseStatusList.aspx" Text="License Status List" Value="License Status List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/MachineLicenseList.aspx" Text="Machine License List" Value="Machine License List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/PositionList.aspx" Text="Position Name List" Value="Position List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ProjectList.aspx" Text="Project Name List" Value="Project List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem PopOutImageUrl="~/Caret6.png" Text="Reports" Value="Reports" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Reports.aspx">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Contractor Laptop inventory.aspx" Text="Contractor Laptop Inventory Report" Value="Contractor Laptop Inventory Report"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Contractor Report.aspx" Text="Contractor Report" Value="Report 3"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/LaptopInventory.aspx" Text="Laptop Inventory Report" Value="Laptop Inventory"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Users and Assigned Computers Report.aspx" Text="Users and Assigned Computers Report" Value="Report 2"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Users with Licenses Report.aspx" Text="Users with Licences Report" Value="Report 1"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/SoftwareList.aspx" Text="Software List" Value="Software List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Servers" Value="Servers" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Servers.aspx" PopOutImageUrl="~/Caret6.png">
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ServerDesignationList.aspx" Text="Server Designation List" Value="Server Designation List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ServerIPList.aspx" Text="Server IP List" Value="Server IP List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ServerListVIPs.aspx" Text="Server VIPs List" Value="Server VIPs "></asp:MenuItem>
                                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/ServerSoftwareList.aspx" Text="Server Software List" Value="Server Software List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/User.aspx" Text="User List" Value="Users List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Users and Roles.aspx" Text="User and Role List" Value="Users and Roles List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/VendorList.aspx" Text="Vendor List" Value="Vendor List"></asp:MenuItem>
                                <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Admin/WebsiteList.aspx" Text="Website List" Value="Website List"></asp:MenuItem>
                              
                                </asp:MenuItem>
                           
                            <asp:MenuItem></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Selectable="False" Text="&nbsp;&nbsp; |" Value="|"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/About.aspx" Text="&nbsp; About &nbsp;" Value="About"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="&nbsp;|" Value="|" Selectable="False"></asp:MenuItem>
                            <asp:MenuItem Text="&nbsp; Help" Value="Help" NavigateUrl="~/Help.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                        </Items>
                        <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#003057" ForeColor="White" />
                        <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="2px" BackColor="#003057" />
                            <StaticMenuStyle BackColor="#003057" />
                        <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#003057" />

                    </asp:Menu>
          
                    </a>
                           </li>

</ul>
      
    </div>         
                       
</nav>
```

and here is an image of how it looks :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WpOj.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say try placing a div around the menu, and float it left:

Say like this:

```
 <div style=float:left>

    -- you menu in here

 </div>
```

However, I think a better approach would be to create a new project, and choose  a template, and that will generate a bootstrap menu bar for you. Then "copy" that menu bar into your existing page.